# How to detach Python debugger in VS Code and let the code finish running?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, detach, vscode-remote

I like running almost everything Python in the VS Code debugger, as it gives me a perfect way to inspect 
variables when hitting unexpected exceptions.

However, once I decide that I want to continue running the code in the background, I see no way of achieving that in VS Code. I can only stop the code completely and re-run, which is often not what I want. In particular, I would like to detach from code when using VS Code Remote SSH, e.g., to reboot my computer that is running the GUI while letting the server in the background finish some computation.

So, how can I detach the debugger from code that was started in VS Code using `ptvsd` without stopping the code?

Answer (score 2):

The Disconnect option (for a debug session, not for SSH) will be more visible with VSCode 1.56 (April 2021)**[strong text](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_other-ui-improvements)**

See [issue 116731](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116731):

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1926584/113000569-3c5ca000-9170-11eb-9fbb-449ec243db6c.gif]

> (in the last part I am holding down the alt key).
>
> - With a "launch" request, I see Stop by default, which changes to Disconnect if I hold ALT.
> - If I click Stop, I get `{"seq":3,"type":"request","command":"disconnect","arguments":{"terminateDebuggee":true}}`
> - If I click Disconnect, I get `{"seq":10,"type":"request","command":"disconnect","arguments":{}}`
> - With "attach", the behavior is reversed.

As noted by the [OP bers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880783/bers) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928764/how-to-detach-python-debugger-in-vs-code-and-let-the-code-finish-running/67208368?noredirect=1#comment119154216_67208368):

> With this release, it is now possible to flip this behavior by pressing the `Alt` modifier while triggering the command from the Debug toolbar.
> Altering the behavior makes it possible to leave the debuggee running for launch type debug sessions, and to terminate the debuggee for attach type debug sessions.
> Apart from using Alt with the default commands, it is also possible to access both the `Debug: Stop` and `Debug: Disconnect` commands from the Command Palette for both launch and attach debug sessions.
>
> **The alternative behavior is only available for debug extensions that have opted in to this feature.**

Comment: Does that apply to Python at all?

Comment: @bers It applies to any debug session, including one for Python.

Comment: Well, I don't see "Debug: Disconnect" for Python - I only see "Debug: Stop".

Comment: @bers Agreed: this is for the next VSCode release.

Comment: I see - in Insiders, the panel with the modified debug actions (including "Disconnect") is indeed there, but it does not seem to work any different from "Stop", even when holding the Alt key. The debugged code does not continue. Also, while the command palette offers "Debug: Stop", it does not offer "Debug: Disconnect".

Comment: From the 1.56.0 [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_other-ui-improvements): "The alternative behavior is only available for debug extensions that have opted in to this feature."

Comment: @bers Thank you for the follow-up: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

There's a disconnect button you can press in the debugger toolbar (looks like a plug). See step 10 in the [remote debugging documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-debugging) for a screenshot and more details.

Comment: Does that apply to code that I started with "F5 or Debug > Start Debugging"? Maybe I should have said that more explicitly in the last sentence of my question. I am using the VS Code Remote SSH extension, so I generally start code simply with F5.

Comment: Probably not, but you can give it a try to see. Otherwise there isn't any other support for detaching from a live process.